# How to do a smart contract for multiswap with Uniswap router?

Tags: solidity, ether, uniswap

I'm looking for a smart contract when I just need to specify in the swap method of uniswap an array of some tokenIN and an array of some tokenOUT (with the amount of course) using the router of uniswap.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, why do you need a smart contract for this? If you just want to interact with Uniswap's router contract, you can do it via Etherscan's API in the contract's page.